# process priority in linux

Tags: linux, kernel

what is the difference between `getpriority()` and `p1.sched_priority`?  That is, what is the difference between

```
getpriority(Prio_process,pid);
```

and

```
struct sched_param p;
sched_getparam(pid,&p);

p.sched_priority;
```

Comment: I think the primary difference is that `getpriority()` only gives you access to `sched_priority`, while `sched_getparam()` gives you access to other pertinent parameters contained in the `struct sched_param`. If all you care about is the `sched_priority`, then `getpriority()` is sufficient and simpler...